# admin page error

Tags: errors

my site have some error. but I don't know why.

[image]

---

### Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNotificationManagerImpl' of undefined

This error occurs in admin post-edit page. I don't know exactly when this error occurs. 
Does anyone have some ideas about this?

Comment: what is your current wordpress version??

Comment: my wordpress version is 4.9.1. and I am using it on localhost.

Comment: You need to re-install the wordpress to overcome this error and visit this : https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3947

Comment: first of all, this is not the only error of me. thanks.